# Windows 10 OpenSSH Server only works 1 time after reboot

Tags: windows-10, python, openssh

I'm new to this topic but I managed to set up the openssh server on a windows 10 machine.

I'm using authentification with keys. Access over the client works (also windows 10) when the server system is freshly booted. When i access via commandline (ssh user@host) and use the 'exit' command, reconnect seems to work fine. But I need to use the ssh connection with python (via Fabric or subprocess). In my python script via vscode it connects on the first run, but when I run the script a second time i get this message in the terminal:

**"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"**

After that I also can’t connect with cmd any more (**"Connection reset by 'IP' 'PORT'"**). I guess it basically means the same... I'm assuming there is an open connection that prevents me from reconnecting?

When I restart the sshd service nothing changes, but when I restart the server machine everything works again (once). Impossible to create my script in that way, so any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "When I restart the service nothing changes ..." - What service are you restarting exactly?  The message you received is displayed where exactly?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment